# Class interface in typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript

I am new to typescript and not that familiar.

I was reading [this blog](https://restful-api-node-typescript.books.dalenguyen.me/en/latest/implement-routing-and-crud.html) on web and trying to comprehend the code

Here the author have created a simple route

```
// /lib/routes/crmRoutes.ts

import {Request, Response} from "express";

export class Routes {
    public routes(app): void {
        app.route('/')
        .get((req: Request, res: Response) => {
            res.status(200).send({
                message: 'GET request successfulll!!!!'
            })
        })
    }
}
```

Which is he is using like this in a kind of main-entry point file

```
// /lib/app.ts

import * as express from "express";
import * as bodyParser from "body-parser";
import { Routes } from "./routes/crmRoutes";

class App {

    public app: express.Application;
    public routePrv: Routes = new Routes();

    constructor() {
        this.app = express();
        this.config();
        this.routePrv.routes(this.app);
    }

    private config(): void{
        this.app.use(bodyParser.json());
        this.app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
    }
}
```

From the definition I read on web, Classes are also like interface in typescript, so this line

```
 public routePrv: Routes = new Routes();
```

Here, Routes is an interface for `routePrv:`? And from my vague understanding, interface usually looks like this

```
interface Person {
  name: string;
  age: number;
}
```

So my question is that, How can a class be an interface and how will our interface look like in case of

```
public routePrv: Routes = new Routes();
```

Can someone please explain the same?

Comment: A class defines a type, yes, but not an interface afaik.

Comment: @Bergi what does this mean here `routePrv: Routes`

Comment: It declares the `routePrv` property to have the type `Routes`

Comment: `routePrv` is of type `Routes`. Classes, interfaces and type literals are all types. Classes are the only type that emits code in the form of a function for es5 and class for es6+. An interface is only an abstract contract, i.e. it cannot contain method implementations whereas a class can.

Answer (score 1):

You are confusing *Interfaces* and *Types*.

An *Interface* (`interface MyInterface {}`) is used to express what an Object has to look like. After typescript transpilation, interfaces are removed. They are more like "hints" for typescript. An example of its usage is this:

```
interface MyInterface {
   myProp:number;
}

const myConst = {myProp: 0}; // implicitly implements MyInterface
const myConst2:MyInterface = {myProp: 0}; // Explicitly tells typescript the type of "myConst2" should be "MyInterface"
const myConst2:MyInterface = {}; // Error, does not implement "MyInterface" correctly

function myFunc(input:MyInterface) {/* Do something */}

myFunc(myConst); // Works
myFunc(myConst2); // Works
myFunc({}); // Fails
```

*Classes* (`class MyClass {}`) boil down to *Constructor Functions*. They are a way of constructing an Object. Since they describe *how* to construct an Object and thus describe the constructed Object's shape, they can also be used to *describe the type* of an Object. Since *Classes* are *Constructor Functions*, they do something during runtime. Hence, only their usages as types are removed.

```
// You can explicitly implement the interface or explicitly, doesn't matter for its usage.
// Explicitly just tells typescript that this class MUST implement the interface
class MyClass /* implements MyInterface */ {
   constructor(public myProp?:number = 0) {}
} 

const myClassConst = new MyClass(); // works
const myClassConst2:MyClass = new MyClass(); // works
const myClassConst3:MyInterface = new MyClass(); // works

myFunc(myClassConst); // works
myFunc(myClassConst2); // works
myFunc(myClassConst3); // works

function myFunc2(input:MyClass) { /* Do something */ }

myFunc2(myClassConst); // works
myFunc2(myClassConst2); // works
myFunc2(myClassConst3); // works
```

As per Request, another example of what does not work:

```
class MyOtherClass {
    constructor(public myProp:number) {}
}

const myOthClassConst = new MyOtherClass(); // works
const myOthClassConst2:MyClass = new MyOtherClass(); // fails, type mismatch
const myOthClassConst3:MyInterface = new MyOtherClass(); // fails, type mismatch

function myFunc3(input:MyOtherClass) {}

myFunc3(myOthClassConst2); // works
myFunc3(myClassConst); // fails, type mismatch
```

**Edit:** Rephrased the explanation due to ambigious meaning (thanks to @Bergi for pointing that out).

Comment: "*Since they describe how to construct an Object, they can also be used to describe the type of an Object.*" - how it is constructed (initialised) is not so important. What matters is what shape the object has (which properties) and what methods are available on it.

Comment: @Bergi and pascalpuetz: Just to confirm, ` public routePrv: Routes = new Routes();` this will only increase readability? besides that it does not have any advantage?

Comment: @anny123 That depends on what part of the statement you mean. `:Routes` tells typescript that the variable MUST be of type `Routes`. So it prevents you from assigning anything to it that is not of type `Routes`. `new Routes` constructs a new Object (advantages if doing that are explained in pretty much every Object Oriented Programming tutorial/book).

Comment: @Bergi That's what I tried to express - as in "if you know how it's created, you also know its final shape". Thanks for pointing out the ambigious meaning.

Comment: @pascalpuetz Thanks a lot for sticking, can you please also include in your example what won't work? and why?

Comment: @anny123 You're very welcome. Could you elaborate what exactly I should add?

Comment: I find it confusing that you talk about the confusion of type and interface but then explain the difference between class and interface.